# Site not showing Image in Wordpress and in HTML code also which uploaded in root what is the solution for this?

Tags: images

Wordpress image is not showing, the URL of the image is giving 404 error, but when I edit the image from the media menu the image is there? but not shown on site anywhere on HTML code embedded in the root also not showing image what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

> the URL of the image is giving 404 error

So the image doesn't exist / has been taken down

> but when I edit the image from the media menu the image is there

The image is saved locally on your computer in the temporary internet files. If you do a hard refresh (Shift + F5), the image will not be shown anymore.

> what should I do?

Save the image, reupload it to any image cloud service (preferably imgur.com), use the URL generated by imgur.